# Ways to access the gradient during an SGD in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit, sgd

I am attempting to alter the implementation of the Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) algorithm in Vowpal Wabbit for logistic regression purposes. I aim to access the computed gradient at each step and perform extra operations before applying the SGD update. Is it possible to achieve this with Vowpal Wabbit?

Comment: You can't access the gradient of SGD. This would require changes within the reduction I'd say.